# angular $scope.$watch on array calling update function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

In [my plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/NGND0MKxxxT7EitZwMk7?p=preview) I have an array of integers, that I have attached $scope.$watch to. When I update the array, my $scope.$watch isnt firing a console.log. Why is my console.log not being called?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="test" ng-controller="testArray">

    <div ng-repeat="item in MyArray track by $index"> {{item}}</div>
    <button ng-click="add()">testing Add</button>
  </body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('test', []);

    app.controller('testArray',['$scope',function($scope){

      $scope.MyArray = [1,2,3,4]

      $scope.add = function(){
        $scope.MyArray.push($scope.MyArray.length+1);
      }
    $scope.$watch('MyArray' , function(){
      console.log($scope.MyArray);
    })
    }]);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$watchCollection`, It would be less expensive than the deep watcher by just providing `true` option in `$watch` function.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('MyArray' , function(){
    console.log($scope.MyArray);
})
```

The `$watchCollection()` goes one-level deep and performs an additional, shallow reference check of the top level items in the collection.

If you have really big array on which you wanted to keep watch then don't go for `$watch` with `true`(deep watcher). For `1000`/`2000` records, you will feel lag in angular bindings. So preferred approach would be avoid `watcher` as much as you can **OR** just go for `$watchCollection`

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to

```
$scope.$watch('MyArray' , function(){
    console.log($scope.MyArray);
}, true)
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), you will see that the third parameter indicate that the $watch method will use object equality to determine if your array has changed. It means that angular will use the  `angular.equals` method that supports arrays comparison, for example

Comment: if you set the third parameters to trus it mean that angular will make a deep watch over the object

Comment: I decided to accept @pankajParkers answer because of the memory performance of watchCollection over using angular.copy

Comment: @RenanLopesFerreira & gh9 Thanks guys. I'd not have added an answer, if you cover the performance related stuff of `deep watcher`. So rather than do edit your answer.. I did added new answer. :-)

Comment: @PankajParkar I didn't know about $watchCollection, so, thank you!